# how to get data from excel sheet with specific code

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

I have one problem with my code I can not achieving mobile no from my code :

```
OleDbCommand cmdoledb = new OleDbCommand("Select [Phone(R)] from [nil$] where [Code]='" + treadcode + "' ", oledbConn);
mobileno = cmdoledb.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
string message = "Dear " + clientname + " Your BSE Trade Position: " + Codemsg + "  Ledger balance is : " + purebalance + ". (Aadinath)";
Int64 len = message.Length;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobileno.Trim()))
{
    dsmsg.Tables[0].Rows.Add(true, message, len, mobileno, clientname, treadcode);
}
else
{
    dsmsg.Tables[0].Rows.Add(true, message, len,"No Mobile Found", clientname, treadcode);
}
```

this is my excel sheet screen shot :

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with _I can not achieving_? Did you get error message? No results? Where is the column [Code] used in your WHERE statement?

Comment: Object reference not found instance..... and getting exception mobile no not found

Comment: If there is no match in the column [Code] for your value then ExecuteScalar will return NULL and calling ToString() on a null will end with the well known NRE exception. You need at least to check what ExecuteScalar returns. Then you should also solve the problem of concatenating strings to create queries. Another well known source of bugs or worse